# need help on php if statement

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin']) || ($_SESSION['loginAdmin'] == '')) {
    header ("Location: loginam.php");
} else {
    include('head2.php');
}


  if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || ($_SESSION['login'] == '')) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
} else {
    include('head3.php'); 
}

?>
```

I'm really stuck at this problem. What I want to do is to be able to redirect the user to another page base on the information entered.

My problem is:

if this statement is true:

```
else {
        include('head3.php'); 
    }
```

This one would also be true:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin']) || ($_SESSION['loginAdmin'] == '')) {
        header ("Location: loginam.php");
    }
```

Leading me to the login page whether I'm admin or just ordinary user. Is it possible two separate the two if statements so that if this is true:

```
else {
    include('head3.php'); 
}
```

Then this statement shouldn't get in the way and redirect me back to the login page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin']) || ($_SESSION['loginAdmin'] == '')) {
    header ("Location: loginam.php");
}
```

Comment: I assume you started the session right after the opening tag, right?

Comment: yup right after the opening is there anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is.. have a variable called usertype...

```
$_SESSION['usertype'] = 1 //for admin
$_SESSION['usertype'] = 2 //for regular user
```

Now Depending on the type of user, you can redirect the user.

```
if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 1)
header ("Location: admin.php");
else if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 2)
header ("Location: user.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Always** use `exit` after sending `Location:` header

Tip: `(!isset($var || $var == '')` could be shortened to `empty($var)`

Comment: I get two headers when I do this.

Comment: @user225269 so, that's why I've told you to use exit. To prevent getting 2 headers. Anyway, no matter what you get, you **ought** tu use exit after location. And you'd better begin to understand that.